# laravel select in nested eager loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a database as follow:

```
Project
_______
id,  project_name, customer_id
431, test,         2

Customer
________
id, customer_name
2,  good_customer

Loe
___
id, mandays, project_id
1,  10,      431
```

I would like to use the eloquent system in laravel and get the following select:

```
{loe_id:1,mandays:10,project_id:431,project_name:'test',customer_id:2,customer_name:'good_customer'}
```

I have tried:

```
$project_loes = Loe::with(['project' => function($query) {
          return $query->select(['id', 'project_name']);
      }])
      ->where('project_id',$id)
      ->get();
```

already there, I m blocking because I get a nested result like:

```
{loe_id:1,mandays:10,project:{id:431,project_name:'test'}}
```

So this is not in one line, I get another {} under project when I would like to have all in one result {}.

Then I can't get how to have the nested part, I have tried:

```
$project_loes = Loe::with(['project' => function($query) {
          return $query->select(['id', 'project_name']);
      },
                              'project.customer' => function($query) {
          return $query->select(['id', 'customer_name']);
      }])
      ->where('project_id',$id)
      ->get();
```

but it gets me back an error and it has to do with the project.customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need to use [joins](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins)

```
$loe = DB::table('loe')
            ->join('project', 'loe.project_id', '=', 'project.id')
            ->join('customer', 'customer.id', '=', 'project.customer_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: So this is the only way to do it, not possible with eloquent???

Comment: Loe::with(['project', 'project.customer'])->get();

Comment: Im pretty sure this is the most conventional method. The method `join` also exists on the `Loe` model btw, so this example is a bit flawed, but it should still work.